# Get rational and irrational parts

Tags: programming, expression-manipulation

Consider an expression of the form $a + b \sqrt{2}$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.  How can I extract $b$ (or equivalently $a$) from this expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can define the conjugate and use it to construct the rational and radical coefficients (`rat` and `rad` resp.).  Just as `PowerExpand` assumes bases are positive reals, `conj[x]` will be correct only if the symbolic variables and functions in an expression `x` represent rational numbers.

```
conj[x_] := x /. Sqrt[2] -> -Sqrt[2];
rat[x_] := (x + conj[x])/2;
rad[x_] := (x - conj[x])/(2 Sqrt[2]);

Through[{rat, rad}[a + b Sqrt[2]]]
(*
  {a, b}
*)

Through[{rat, rad}[(a + b Sqrt[2])^2]]
% // Simplify

(*
  { 1/2 ((a - Sqrt[2] b)^2 + (a + Sqrt[2] b)^2),
    (-(a - Sqrt[2] b)^2 + (a + Sqrt[2] b)^2)/(2 Sqrt[2]) }
  {a^2 + 2 b^2, 2 a b}
*)

Simplify@Through[{rat, rad}[(3 - 2 Sqrt[2])/10]]
(*
  {3/10, -(1/5)}
*)
```

More generally, one can extend the definitions to numbers over an arbitrary quadratic extension of the rationals.

```
Clear[conj, rat, rad];
conj[x_, sqroot_: Sqrt[2]] := x /. sqroot -> -sqroot;
rat[x_, sqroot_: Sqrt[2]] := (x + conj[x, sqroot])/2;
rad[x_, sqroot_: Sqrt[2]] := (x - conj[x, sqroot])/(2 sqroot);
```

Comment: Yes, of course.  Very clever solution.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `ToNumberField`:

```
2/3 + 1/4 Sqrt[2]
ToNumberField[%, Sqrt[2]]
```

which produces

```
AlgebraicNumber[Sqrt[2], {2/3, 1/4}]
```

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks!

Comment: What if $a$ and $b$ are symbolic?

Comment: @TysonWilliams: I'm not sure how to handle that case, as I rarely use the abstract algebra functions. However, Daniel Lichtblau might know how to do it, so you could try asking him (or you could ask it as another question).

Comment: As a mathematician / theoretical computer scientist, I think of $a$ and $b$ as "symbolically rational" (i.e. some rational numbers by assumption). Of course I also know, but often forget, that (1) symbolic, (2) symbolically rational, and (3) and rational are three different "data types" that can all behave differently in Mathematica.

Comment: BTW: One can use `ToNumberField[num][[2, 1]]` to extract the rational part ("`a`") of any quadratic field. No need to even specify the generator!