# Simplify Class invariant $G(25)$

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

How to simplify 
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-5 \pi }\right)}}{\sqrt[12]{2}
   \sqrt[6]{\vartheta _2\left(0,e^{-5 \pi }\right) \vartheta _4\left(0,e^{-5 \pi
   }\right)}}$$

This is a Ramanujan's Class Invariant $G(25)$.

Class invariant is defined as $G(n)=(2k(e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}})k'(e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}))^{-1/12}$, Where $k(q)$ is a [Elliptic Modulus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticModulus.html)

```
k[q_] := (EllipticTheta[2, 0, q]/EllipticTheta[3, 0, q])^2

kc[q_] := (EllipticTheta[4, 0, q]/EllipticTheta[3, 0, q])^2

G[n_] := (2 k[E^(-Pi Sqrt[n])] kc[E^(-Pi Sqrt[n])])^(-1/12)

G[25] // N 

1.61803
```

I know that $G(25)$ is the golden ratio  $$G(25)=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
But "FullSimplify" doesn't work

```
G[25] // FullSimplify
```

Sorry for my English. Thanks!

Comment: You can reduce this problem to showing that `ModularLambda[5 I] == 
 Root[1 - 414728 #1 + 414744 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 &, 1]`. I'm not sure how to get *Mathematica* to do this, however, as its modular functions are not aware of the special algebraic values.

Answer (score 1):

```
k[q_] := (EllipticTheta[2, 0, q]/EllipticTheta[3, 0, q])^2
kc[q_] := (EllipticTheta[4, 0, q]/EllipticTheta[3, 0, q])^2
G[n_] := (2 k[E^(-Pi Sqrt[n])] kc[E^(-Pi Sqrt[n])])^(-1/12)

TrueQ[G[25] == N@GoldenRatio]

(*True*)
```

If you want a more exact solution, you might want to check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67293/get-rational-and-irrational-parts) out.

Comment: Try e.g. `TrueQ[G[25] == N[GoldenRatio + 1/10^14]]`.   Even though you get true it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's right. But I will keep the answer for reference.